# not able to make the code await using 'await' till a function completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm calling a local function, it has to wait for that local function's result to continue further.

this is my local function

```
var Messagehome =  (req, res) => {
  user.find().exec(async (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    let p = await getfulluser(req.User._id);

    list = user.filter((u) => u._id != req.User._id);

    console.time("time1");
    for (let i = 0; i < p.messages.length; i++) {
      for (let e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
        if (list[e]._id.equals(p.messages[i]._id)) {
          list.splice(e, 1);
          break;
        } else {
          console.log(list[e].name);
          list[e].password = undefined;
        }
      }
    }
    console.timeEnd("time1");
    return res.json(list), list;
  });
};

exports.Messagehome = Messagehome;
```

I want to use Messagehome in this function. It has to wait for Messagehome to continue 'for loop'.I tried await, but it didn't work

```
exports.refreshfind = async (req, res) => {
  let { id } = req.body;

  if (list) {
    console.time("TIME   1");
    for (let e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
      if (list[e]._id.equals(id)) {
        list.splice(e, 1);
        res.json(list);
        console.timeEnd("TIME   1");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!list) {
    console.time("TIME    2");
    Messagehome();
    for (let e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
      if (list[e]._id.equals(id)) {
        list.splice(e, 1);
        res.json(list);
        console.timeEnd("TIME    2");
        break;
      }
    }

  }
};
```

I'm getting this error

```
(node:13396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at exports.refreshfind (D:\message\backend\controllers\message.js:58:30)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at D:\message\backend\controllers\user.js:94:5
    at D:\message\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:223:12
    at getSecret (D:\message\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (D:\message\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
    at exports.isSignedIn (D:\message\backend\controllers\user.js:89:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\message\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
(node:13396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13396) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:13396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'User' of undefined
    at D:\message\backend\controllers\message.js:14:35
    at D:\message\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4599:16
    at D:\message\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:264:16
    at D:\message\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4326:11
    at D:\message\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
(node:13396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

It couldn't read 'length' from   if( ! list ) in refreshfind.

I tried await for Messagehome and for loop, but it didn't work

```
 if (!list) {
    console.time("TIME    2");
    Messagehome();
    for (let e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
      if (list[e]._id.equals(id)) {
        list.splice(e, 1);
        res.json(list);
        console.timeEnd("TIME    2");
        break;
      }
    }

  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, you definitely should use `await Messagehome();`. However, you'll also need to fix the `Messagehome` implementation to [properly promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) `user.find().exec()`. Never pass an `async function` as a callback. (And last but not least you declared two parameters for `Messagehome` but are not passing any arguments).

Comment: Whatever `user.find().exec` is, it doesn't return anything that could be awaited. I'd try to look into its docs to see if it supports `var user = await user.find()`. This would let you refactor the code to correctly work with `async/await`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Given the stack trace it appears to be mongoose, so yes that's supported and is the proper solution.

Comment: yes, it's mongoose,as you told I have used promise in Messagehome,I replaced `res` with `resolve`, but it's getting error in `req.User._id`

Comment: i used promise in this way `var Messagehome = (req, res) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` . replacing `res` with `resolve` didn't work

Comment: @ram `res` was a http response, `resolve` is a promise resolver function. They work completely different. What exactly do you want `Messagehome` and `refreshfind` to actually do?

Comment: I have used `list` in both the functions, it's a global variable.`list` gets it's value only from `Messagehome`,which is called only when the web app has just started from both frontend and backend. When I was testing the backend and resaved it, the `list`  became null by it's default value.Now in the front end, if i didn't refresh the page and use the `refreshfind` related things, they didn't work, because the list is empty in backend. I'm a fresher, I don't know what happens when real web is refreshed or reloaded.If backend is refreshed and front isn't,I don't want create problem to users

Comment: I wonder if you are struggling with [session variables in Node](https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some solution from live chat room.
Since Messagehome(req,res) is defined with req, res, I have to call it in the same way as

```
Messagehome(req,res)
```

and this is not going to work

```
Messagehome()
```

I found the remaining solution by studying promise.
Messagehome must be a promise based function to await when it's called. 
 This is the complete solution

```
var Messagehome =  (req, res) =>  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  user.find().exec(async (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    let p = await getfulluser(req.User._id);

    list = user.filter((u) => u._id != req.User._id);

    console.time("time1");
    for (let i = 0; i < p.messages.length; i++) {
      for (let e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
        if (list[e]._id.equals(p.messages[i]._id)) {
          list.splice(e, 1);
          break;
        } else {
          console.log(list[e].name);
          list[e].password = undefined;
        }
      }
    }
    console.timeEnd("time1");
     res.json(list);
     resolve (list)
  });
})

exports.Messagehome = Messagehome;
```

since Messagehome is promise based function, it's going to wait till that promise completes.So i can get list from Messagehome in refreshfind

```
exports.refreshfind = async (req, res) => {
  let { id } = req.body;

  if (list) {
    console.time("TIME   1");
    for (let e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
      if (list[e]._id.equals(id)) {
        list.splice(e, 1);
        res.json(list);
        console.timeEnd("TIME   1");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!list) {
    console.time("TIME    2");
   await Messagehome(req,res);
    for (let e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
      if (list[e]._id.equals(id)) {
        list.splice(e, 1);
        res.json(list);
        console.timeEnd("TIME    2");
        break;
      }
    }

  }
};
```

Now await is going to really wait for me